# Using a progress bar outside of a loop for a web scraping application

Tags: python, web-scraping, progress-bar

My code has the following format

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Stuff = List()
# ....
def website_1(url): #...
def website_2(url): #...
def website_3(url): #...
def website_4(url): #...
# ....

# I want to print a progress bar here
website_1(url1)
website_2(url2)
website_3(url3)
website_4(url4)
# End of progress bar
```

Every website_ function extracts data from different URLs.
They all follow the following format

```
def website_(url):
    soup,browser = load_soup(url)
    text = soup.findAll('...', class_='...')
    browser.quit()
    for t in text:
        # ...
        Stuff.append()
```

Since I am not using a for loop outside these functions,
is it possible to print one progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can print progress bar like this (python 2):

```
import sys
def show_progress(progress):
    print "\r" , str(progress) +"%" , "finished" , "|"+"#"*(progress/5)+"|" , "/-\|."[progress/3%5] ,
    sys.stdout.flush()


from time import sleep
progress = 0
while progress <= 100:
    show_progress(progress)
    progress += 1
    sleep(0.1)
print "\b\b \nScraping finished."
```

and in your code:

```
def website_(url):
    soup,browser = load_soup(url)
    text = soup.findAll('...', class_='...')
    browser.quit()
    for index, t in enumerate(text):
        # ...
        show_progress(int(float(index)*100/len(text)))
        Stuff.append()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I want print only one progress bar. But do I have to add a progress bar in every function, since I am using four different ones?